# many to many association foreign key changeset error

Tags: elixir, ecto

For `has_*` we have `no_assoc_constraint`. It works fine and throw a changeset error when we try to delete a parent and the child still exists. Is there any function which will work for `many to many`.

Like these three schemas

```
   schema "facilities" do         
    field(:name, :string)
    field(:description, :string)
    field(:is_active, :boolean, default: true)


    many_to_many(:users, User, join_through: "users_facilities")
  end

   schema "users_facilities" do
    belongs_to(:user, User, primary_key: true)
    belongs_to(:facility, Facility, primary_key: true)
   end

   schema "users" do
    field(:first_name, :string)
    field(:last_name, :string)
    field(:email_address, :string)
    field(:username, :string)
    many_to_many(:facilities, Facility, join_through: 
   "users_facilities")
```

When ever I try to delete a facility whose foreign key is present in the user_facilities . I want to get the changeset error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging I found that we can use `foreign_key_constraint` to generate changeset errors for any type of association by providing the foreign key name  like this

```
    record
       |> Ecto.Changeset.change()
       |> Ecto.Changeset.foreign_key_constraint(:users, name: :users_facilities_facility_id_fkey,
         message: "are still associated with id}"
        )
```

It works but I think it would be better though if we don't have to specify the `name: foreign_key_name` explicitly every time.